# ERROR running force:package:create: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

Can someone please help for the below error?

my **sfdx-project.json** file is as follows:

[image: { "packageDirectories": [ { "path": "force-app", "default": true } ], "namespace": "ns1", "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://pussinboots7-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com", "sourceApiVersion": "55.0" }]

when I hit the below command I get an error like Unexpected end of JSON input

> > sfdx force:package:create --name "pussinboots" --description "pussinboots" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app

> > ERROR running force:package:create:  Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with your `sfdx-project.json`. You should [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: @DerekF Thanks!! and I just added that file and can you please help me the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your root folder, where we have a .sfdx/ folder, there might be a json file which has a zero byte file. You might be wondering how to detect a zero byte file in .sfdx/ folder if you have more than 100 files. Please execute below command in bash terminal

```
$ find . -type f -empty
```

Once you execute above command, please remove files which has been detected as zero byte.

```
$ rm -rf <NAME OF YOUR FILE>
```

More details: https://dev.to/praneethkumarpidugu/unexpected-end-of-json-input-in-visual-studio-code-1mim

Now SFDX behind the scenes is happy and feel free to try to reauthorize or change orgs. You should be good

Comment: works like charm on macOS thanks!